# renderHook returns undefined

Tags: testing, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useCounter = (initialValue = 10) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(initialValue);

  const increaseCounter = (value = 1) => {
    setCounter(counter + value);
  };

  const resetCounter = () => {
    setCounter(initialValue);
  };

  const decreaseCounter = (value = 1) => {
    if (counter - value > 0) {
      setCounter(counter - value);
    }
  };

  console.log(counter);

  return {
    counter,
    increaseCounter,
    resetCounter,
    decreaseCounter,
  };
};
```

and to test it I have this test:

```
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useCounter } from "../../src/hooks";

describe("Testing useCounter", () => {
  test("Debe retornar los valores por defecto", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => {
      useCounter(2);
    });
    console.log(result.current);
  });
});
```

However result is undefined, instead to have the different properties the custom hook is returning.

The console.log in the hook is displayed with the expected value.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Either replace () => {useCounter(2);} with () => useCounter(2)  or do return useCounter(2). Right now () => {} is a function that does not return anything. So result will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the comment by [@Marko Taht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3071712/marko-taht).

The callback inside of `renderHook` below returns an implicit `undefined`.

> "A function returns undefined if a value was not returned" from [the MDN docs covering the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#description).

The OP's code:

```js
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useCounter } from "../../src/hooks";

describe("Testing useCounter", () => {
  test("Debe retornar los valores por defecto", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => {
      useCounter(2);
    });
    console.log(result.current);
  });
});
```

should change to either of the following.

#### Including a return statement in brackets

```js
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useCounter } from "../../src/hooks";

describe("Testing useCounter", () => {
  test("Debe retornar los valores por defecto", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => {
      return useCounter(2);
    });
    console.log(result.current);
  });
});
```

Specifically, changing the `renderHook` callback to `return` the `useCounter(2)` hook result:

```js
{
  return useCounter(2);
}
```

#### Arrow function without the return or brackets

```js
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useCounter } from "../../src/hooks";

describe("Testing useCounter", () => {
  test("Debe retornar los valores por defecto", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useCounter(2));
    console.log(result.current);
  });
});
```

Specifically, removing the brackets from the `renderHook` callback:

```js
useCounter(2);
```